# webXml not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Im using maven-war-plugin in a non-standar file structure.

I can't change the folder names nor the structure; so i use the following to overcome those problems:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>myProject</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>myProject</warName>
                        <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        <webXml>${project.basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see, the name of the folder is diferent, but Netbeans find it without problems. I can even see them web. From the project view in the IDE.

But when i try to compile, maven fails to find the web.xml (wich is in that route)

I've already compared the web.xml file path agains the efective pom's path of the webXml tag and they are the same.

I have tried changing the version of the plugin, but it's worthless.

Please help.

Comment: if you don't specify `webXml` does it build the war file without it?

Comment: Have you tried using the true path to the web.xml?

Comment: I tried both aproach and none of them work. However @Sean Kuhlman
 found my error. His answer is correct. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `configuration` block should be within `plugin` and not within `executions`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>myProject</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <warName>myProject</warName>
        <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <webXml>${project.basedir}\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```